# app not displaying

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application that isn't very active but a few people seem to like it. It stopped working for them a few days ago. I haven't been keeping up to speed about all the developer things I'm supposed to do lately. Can anyone point me in the right direction? What did facebook turn off a few days ago that could make my application display a blank page?

If you don't think this question shows enough research effort that's fine, can you link me to something and I'll figure it out for myself? I was used to the old developer forum and this stack overflow thing is just plain awful. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Consider checking the [blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/). Reading the following [post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/567/), it seems that your app requires supporting OAuth 2.0 and HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you. I read the post and followed the links.

My site already had SSL, but I was pointing it to a different directory on the server. I upgraded the php sdk, and changed getsession to getuser, but I kept the $session variable instead of changing it to $user. I was always using the signed_request parameter.

Everything is still the same. One thing I had to do as a work around was to reference the channel file and do a little javascript to make sure my canvas app always scrolled. Did the new upgrade mess with that workaround?

Thanks again for any help you can provide.